# Why for loop does not change element in a numeric vector?

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

Element in a numeric vector does not change after running a for loop that iterates each element.

I have a numeric vector:

```
>str(df$Grad.Rate)
num [1:777] 60 56 54 59 15 55 63 73 80 52 ...
```

I want to update any element>100

```
> for (i in df$Grad.Rate){
+     if (i >100){
+         print(i)
+         i = 100
+         print(paste0('changed to ', i))
+     }
+ }
[1] 118
[1] "changed to 100"
```

After I run the for loop, the element that is >100 is still in the vector

```
> any(df$Grad.Rate>100)
[1] TRUE
```

Why?

Comment: You are just `print`ing  and not updating the dataset.  You may need to loop through the sequence and update it.  But, this can be done easily without a loop, `df$Grad.Rate[df$Grad.Rate > 100] <- 100` or `df$Grad_Rate <- pmax(100, df$Grad.Rate)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `i = 100`, you have to use

```
df$Grad.Rate[i] <- 100
```

in your loop. You can also choose to change the elements without a loop:

```
df$Grad.Rate[df$Grad.Rate > 100] <- 100
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without any loop

```
df$Grad.Rate[df$Grad.Rate > 100] <- 100
```

Or

```
df$Grad_Rate <- pmin(100, df$Grad.Rate)
```

---

In the `for` loop, the values are not updated.  Instead, we can loop through the sequence and update it

```
for (i in seq_along(df$Grad.Rate)){
 if (df$Grad.Rate[i] >100){

     df$Grad.Rate[i] <- 100

  }
```